# ~てはしない form grammar

Tags: grammar

I've seen this a few times and always just been guessing the meaning. I have this dialogue were 勝てはしない is said. Is ...てはしない used for emphasis? Saying that winning can't be done?

I'm just curious why I never read about this grammar in my books or anywhere else. Is it like saying it is impossible? Like 勝ち得ない or something. I'd like your help. Dialogue under with my attempted translation.

深海王を狩るつもりならやめておけ
If your intention is about to hunt the deep sea king leave it for me

深海王?
The deep sea king?

ヒーローごときが束になっても勝てはしない
Even if heroes bunch together we can't win

Comment: I don't know why it's not on your grammar book, but it's a FAQ. Here's [a list of previous questions](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reny%C5%8Dkei%20particle-%E3%81%AF).